# Retrieve safety data from omnetpp and sumo

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm running a simulation based on SUMO, OMNeT++ and veins, and I want to see the influence of connectivity on traffic safety. Thus, I add several 'SSM' command in my router file.

When I ran sumo individually, it will give me the output of the vehicle which has SSM device, such as TTC and PET. Each SSM device will have its own output file, named 'ssm_id.xml'

However, when I ran SUMO,  OMNeT++ and Veins together, the output of SSM device is missed, I cannot find them.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might (1) have configured SUMO to write the output files to the directory from which you are running the simulation and you might (2) be using `sumo-launchd.py` to run one copy of SUMO for each simulation. By default, `sumo-launchd.py` runs the SUMO simulation by copying all files to a temporary directory (which is deleted when the simulation completes). Hence, your output files are deleted.

Thus, there are three ways to retain your output files:

- configure SUMO to write output files elsewhere (using an absolute
  path)
- ask `sumo-launchd.py` to not delete the temporary directory
- use a different way of running SUMO (e.g., using the [TraCIScenarioManagerForker](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.ned) module instead of the default one)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used an absolute path to save my output. The weird thing is when I ran sumo solely, the output XML file is complete., which is the output of SSM device. However, when I ran SUMO with omnetpp, the output XML file turn out to be an incomplete file with several missing columns.  Do you know why this would happen? Thank you!